# Can't assign requested address, C++ UDP sockets

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, udp, winsock

The following code is from http://digitalpbk.blogspot.com/2007/10/unix-networking-sockets-udp-transmitter.html, It runs fine on localhost but when I change it to my ip it gives the error

bind(): Can't assign requested address

I have been searching for a solution for a few hours so any help would be great

```
int main(void)
{

 struct sockaddr_in sin;
 char msg[10000];
 int ret;
 int sin_length;


 int s;

 s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
 if(!s)
 {
  perror("socket()");
  return 0;
 }
 sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
 sin.sin_port = htons(65000);
 sin.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("24.212.11.211"); // ---------------- This line ----------------
 if(bind(s, (struct sockaddr *)&sin, sizeof(sin)))
 {
  perror("bind()");
  return 1;
 }


 do  // I think the following might be a problem
 {
  sin_length = sizeof(sin);
  ret = recvfrom(s, msg, 10000, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&sin, (socklen_t*) &sin_length);
//Waits until a message is recieved...
  printf("Message[%s:%d] : %s\n",
  inet_ntoa(sin.sin_addr), sin.sin_port,msg);
 }
 while(msg[0]!='0');

 close(s);
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is there already something bound to that port/address combination?

Comment: The obvious question then would be is `24.212.11.211` an IP address on that machine?

Comment: Can you check the 'errno' value? It might provide more info (as per http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/bind.html).

Comment: What is the output of ipconfig (or ifconfig on Linux)?

Comment: My routers IP, I get the same error but 0.0.0.0 works so I will try that!

Comment: @SuperPaperSam: if my answer helped you, it would be much appreciated if you hit the checkmark on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely you're changing it to the IP that people see you as, not the IP you see yourself as. (Assuming windows from the parameters the functions take) Go to start -> control panel -> (Network & Internet ->) network connection/change network adapter settings and then right click on your network adapter and select status, look at IP address, that is the one you should be using in your code. If you don't want to worry about that, you can always use the BIND TO ALL THE THINGS address, 0.0.0.0.

Comment: A better way to see the IP address is to use `ipconfig`, since the network adapter configuration will most likely be to obtain an IP via DHCP (thus rendering your suggestion not helpful).

Comment: @Eli ipconfig will show you the same thing as the network adapter configuration, your IP is not going to magically change depending on which method you use.

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought you meant something else. Indeed, pressing the `Details...` will show the IP address.