# "Can't assign requested address" when sending to a UdpSocket

Tags: sockets, rust, udp

```
let addr = "239.255.255.250:1982";
let socket = UdpSocket::bind(addr).unwrap();
let message = "some message".as_bytes();
socket.send_to(message, addr).unwrap();
```

This code gives the following error for the last line:

```
Error { repr: Os { code: 49, message: "Can\'t assign requested address" } }
```

Why would that be the case?

EDIT:
I tried the following as suggested:

```
let addr = "239.255.255.250:1982";
let socket = UdpSocket::bind("127.0.0.1:34254").unwrap();
let message = "some message".as_bytes();
socket.send_to(message, addr).unwrap();
```

But that didn't change anything, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7383682/8399495), I changed the address to "0.0.0.0:34254", and it worked:

```
let addr = "239.255.255.250:1982";
let socket = UdpSocket::bind("0.0.0.0:34254").unwrap();
let message = "some message".as_bytes();
socket.send_to(message, addr).unwrap();
```

Answer (score 6):

The address you used to bind your `UdpSocket` to is a multicast address.

The argument to [`UdpSocket::bind`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/struct.UdpSocket.html#method.bind) should be the local address you send *from*.

[The docs use `127.0.0.1:34254`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/struct.UdpSocket.html#method.send_to). If it is not currently being used, this should work for you. Additionally you can give it an array of potential adresses to use.